# Correct behaviour? - iPhone app running on iPad loads xib with ~ipad extension

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder, xib

I've stumbled across what I think is some odd behaviour in iOS - a search of StackOverflow hasn't turned up anything identical to my problem.

Essentially, if you have two .xib files with device modifiers (~iphone and ~ipad), and you run an iPhone app (NOT universal) on the iPad (i.e. within the iPhone simulator window) it will attempt to load the ~ipad xib file rather than the ~iphone xib.

Is this a bug?  I would expect the ~iphone xib to be loaded.  Even though the actual device is an iPad, it's emulating an iPhone, right?  So surely it should load the iPhone interface file?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new iPhone (not universal) app in XCode - use the 'Single View' template.
2. Rename ViewController.xib to ViewController~iphone.xib
3. Duplicate and rename the xib, so that you now have ViewController~iphone.xib and ViewController~ipad.xib
4. Run this iPhone app within the iPad simulator (or on an actual iPad device) - the ~ipad XIB is loaded rather than the ~iPhone xib.

Can anyone suggest how I might work around this issue?  It's complicated because my actual XCode project has multiple targets (1. iPhone-only app 2. iPad-only app) so I need to support all scenarios, hence the use of device modifiers.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. I renamed my *~ipad.xib to *-ipad.xib and select the appropriate xib file in code with [UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this when working with nibs:

```
- (id)init
{
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomiPhone )
    {
        nibNameString = @"mynib-iPhone";
    }
    else
    {
        nibNameString = @"mynib-iPad";
    }
    self = [super initWithnNibName:nibNameString bundle...
```

Comment: I also think what's happening is you have copied an iPhone nib, when it should be an iPad nib.  Try creating an iPad project, then copy the nib from that to your iPhone project instead of duplicating the iPhone project nib.